# What does the "Set public save location" setting mean in Windows Explorer Libraries?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-libraries

### Libraries in Windows Explorer

In Windows Explorer you can use libraries to join the content of multiple folders into one place. The libraries, that you can see in your user account in Windows Explorer, are defined in simple XML files like `Videos.library-ms` and saved under `C:\Users\UserAccout\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries`. If you open a library in Windows Explorer, the files from all source folders, that are defined as locations for the library, are displayed.

### Save Location

When you create, save or paste a file inside a library in Windows Explorer, it is saved in one of the locations of the library. You can define that location by setting the default save location in the library's proerties.

There is another option to set the public save location (`Set public save location`). What does that setting do?

[Library Porperties Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5idn.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's a folder where all users of the computer can place content so that everyone else can see it.

Comment: No, it sounds like that, but it doesn't work. Have you tested it? I have created a library in UserAccount1 and added a folder to the library. The folder is set to save location and set to public save location. But UserAccount2 can't see the library and therefore cannot save files to the library or the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's this:
[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-isdefaultnonownersavelocation](http://System.IsDefaultNonOwnerSaveLocation)

> Identifies the default save location for a library for non-owners of
> the library.

Which impies that a `Library` folder can be shared. Indeed, in the `Public` proifle folder, we find a `Libraires` folder:
( test folder added )
[image]

and if more than one public folder were added to a Public Library, this designation is a perfect parallel to the default save location for a single-user folder that references multiple locations.
Most-likely, an individual can share a Library with other users as they can folders. But I don't have any practical knowledge in that area and can only hope one who does may share theirs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I can understand that in theory, the "public save location" is the place where files from other users than the owner of the library are saved. But HOW in reality can you save a file in a library if you are a user that doesn't own the library? You cannot see lbraries if you are not the owner and they are not stored in your own account. And what's this `Users\Public\Libraries` folder about? If it worked similar to the other folders in `Users\Public` you would have to see the content of that folder in the individual user accounts. But I don't see TV recordings anywhere.

Comment: Also there's this `Shared` option which is always greyed out. On one of my computers it is set to `Shared` for all default libraries. On another of my computers it is **not** set to `Shared`. I never used or touched libraries before on both of that computers but for some reason the settings are different. And you cannot even change that option manually.

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with all the intricacies of sharing. I play on a standalone machine so no practical experience with multiple devices & multiple users. `Recorded TV` appeared as an empty library on my machine & I added a locaftion for testing. It probably only appears on `Home`, and not other editions. Try creating a library under `Public` folder so it's available to all & test with another account on the same computer. It may also be left over from `HomeGroup` functionality, I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe this can work, I will try. Still some of these settings just don't make any sense to me.